# How can I change de size of the title in my navigation bar to fit a text

Tags: ios, uilabel, uinavigationbar

Well I need to change a text on my navigation control bar to fit a movie "title" longer than the space available. I've see more code for resize the text using a label like this:

```
  UILabel *bigLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 30)];
bigLabel.text = titoloSource;
bigLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:22.0];
[bigLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0]];
[bigLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[bigLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[bigLabel setText:self.title];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem setTitleView:bigLabel];
self.navigationItem.titleView = bigLabel;
```

But I Know that the appel GUI line guide say that we can't make a small text below a certain measure. Now I've think: WHY CAN'T I MAKE an animated slider text?

So, Someone know a way to make a text animated that scroll all the "title" inside a label???

thanks

Comment: you should probably add tags for the language, platform and framework that you are using. I think it's Objective-C and iOS but since I'm not sure I won't re-tag it myself.

Comment: FWIW I think a scrolling title is not great UI design. You might consider letting it truncate and, if necessary, adding the title inside the main view.